# How to be sure about the limit of a given sequence?

Tags: calculus, limits

For example:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(\sqrt{n^2+2n}-\sqrt{n^2-2n})=(\sqrt{n^2+2n}-\sqrt{n^2-2n})(\frac{\sqrt{n^2+2n}+\sqrt{n^2-2n}}{\sqrt{n^2+2n}+\sqrt{n^2-2n}})=\frac{4n}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n-2})}=\frac{\lim_{n\to\infty}4n=\infty}{\lim_{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n-2})}=\infty}=>\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n-2})=O(n).
$$

But actually the limit is 2. How could I know that I have to search for an atcual limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know befeore, we need to calculate properly, for this particular case form here

$$...=\frac{4n}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n-2})}=\frac n {\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n}}\frac{4}{(\sqrt{1+2/n}+\sqrt{1-2/n})}\to 2$$

Comment: So I have to play with it until I get the limit and I have no way to know when to stop? btw the limit is 2.

Comment: @MorHaham Opsss...fixed! Yes exactly we can't know at start if the limit exists or not! we need to calculate and if we think that it doesn't exists we need to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Well. You have
\begin{align}
\frac{4n}{\sqrt{n}(\sqrt{n+2}+\sqrt{n-2}} = \frac{4}{(\sqrt{1+2/n}+\sqrt{1-2/n)}}\rightarrow 2
\end{align}

Comment: The question is how do I know whether to continue looking for the limit or there is no limit at all?

Comment: @MorHaham Unfortunately, I don't know how to answer such a question. For one, given a limit problem, you know that it either converge or not. So if you can't find a limit then you must show that the limit doesn't exist. Otherwise, you keep trying to compute the limit.